# Reactivity inside Shiny modules NOT working

Tags: r, shiny

I am struggling with reactivity inside shiny modules.
I am trying to use a checkboxgroupInput and a reactive database depending on the selections inside the module with NO success.
My code:

```
library(shiny)
library(data.table)

country <- c('Argentina', 'United States', 'Peru', 'India', 'United Kingdom', 'Colombia','Others',
   'Argentina', 'United States', 'Peru', 'India', 'United Kingdom', 'Colombia','Others')
value1 <- c(1,4,2,5,7,8,9,4,3,2,1,1,4,8)
value2 <- c(6,5,7,9,0,4,3,3,5,6,7,1,2,3)

data <- data.table(country,value1, value2)


# MODULE UI 
module_UI <- function(id) {
 ns <- NS(id)
  fluidRow(
        uiOutput(ns('choose_countries')),
        verbatimTextOutput(ns("countries")),
        verbatimTextOutput(ns("mean"))
     )

}

# MODULE Server
module_OUT <- function(input, output, session, df, metric) {

  # countries selector
  output$choose_countries <- renderUI({
checkboxGroupInput("choose_countries", label = "Choose countries:",
                   choices = list('Argentina', 'United States', 'Peru', 'India', 'United Kingdom', 'Colombia','Others'),
                   selected = c('Argentina', 'United States', 'Peru', 'India', 'United Kingdom', 'Colombia', 'Others'), inline = T)
  })

  output$countries <- renderPrint({ input$choose_countries })

  react_df <- reactive({
    react_df <- df[country %in% input$choose_countries,]

  })

  output$mean <- renderPrint({ mean(react_df()$metric)})
} 


# App ui
library(shinydashboard)
ui <- fluidPage(
  module_UI("test_1")
)

# App server
server <- function(input, output,session){
   callModule(module_OUT, "test_1", data, 'value1')

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

No selected country is shown nor the mean of the selected metric.

I have tested this simple code without the use of modules and works fine.

Any ideas? Thanks in advance

Comment: Use `session$ns("choose_countries")` as the inputId for the render UI function.

Comment: using `ns <- session$ns` as suggested by @ greg L or  `session$ns("choose_countries")` as suggested by @ Ryan Morton make the `output$countries` work OK, but did not help with the `output$mean` ... what is my real issue (the reactivity inside the module)...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use dynamic UI in a module, be sure that the input IDs are properly namespaced.

```
module_OUT <- function(input, output, session, df, metric) {
  ns <- session$ns
  
  # countries selector
  output$choose_countries <- renderUI({
    checkboxGroupInput(ns("choose_countries"), label = "Choose countries:",
                       choices = list('Argentina', 'United States', 'Peru', 'India', 'United Kingdom', 'Colombia','Others'),
                       selected = c('Argentina', 'United States', 'Peru', 'India', 'United Kingdom', 'Colombia', 'Others'), inline = T)
  })
```

---

> #### Using renderUI within modules
>
> Inside of a module, you may want to use `uiOutput`/`renderUI`. If your `renderUI` block itself contains inputs/outputs, you need to use `ns()` to wrap your ID arguments, just like in the examples above. But those `ns` instances were created using `NS(id)`, and in this case, there’s no id parameter to use. What to do?
>
> The session parameter can provide the `ns` for you; just call `ns <- session$ns`. This will put the ID in the same namespace as the session.

https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/modules.html

Comment: using `ns <- session$ns` as suggested by @ greg L or  `session$ns("choose_countries")` as suggested by @ Ryan Morton make the `output$countries` work OK, but did not help with the `output$mean` ... what is my real issue (the reactivity inside the module)...

Comment: That issue has nothing to do with the reactivity.  The code is just wrong.  Try something like: `mean(react_df()[[metric]])`